# Typescript map function local variable syntax

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, typescript

I am wondering what the proper syntax is for declaring a variable within the scope of a map function? I getting getting error ";" expected but still not sure where to put it or why?

```
<ListGroup className="cSkills">
{ jobPosting.commonsSkills ? 
    jobPosting.commonsSkills.map((skill) => {
        let aColor = "blue";
        if (skill.isAddedByUser) {
            aColor = "green";
        }
        <ListGroupItem style={{color: aColor}}> {skill.name} </ListGroupItem> // error here
    )
    : null
}}
</ListGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you format your code in a more reasonable way then it will be easier to see the problems.

(1) You need to close the arrow function right after the `ListGroupItem` (you currently only close it when you do `}}`)

(2) You need to use the `return` keyword

It should look like this:

```
<ListGroup className="cSkills">
{ jobPosting.commonsSkills ? 
    jobPosting.commonsSkills.map((skill) => {
        let aColor = "blue";
        if (skill.isAddedByUser) {
            aColor = "green";
        }
        return <ListGroupItem style={{color: aColor}}> {skill.name} </ListGroupItem>
    })
    : null
}
</ListGroup>
```